# Composer windows compatible scripts

Tags: php, windows, composer-php, compatibility

I'm facing a small issue here. I'm trying to use composer's script to lint my PHP project. So far what I've done is have a composer file, and enter some scripts in them. My snippet of composer file looks something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "document": "vendor/bin/apigen generate -s ./src -d ./docs",
    "codecept": "vendor/bin/codecept",
    "test": "vendor/bin/codecept run",
    "lint": "vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PSR2 src",
    "bootstrap": "composer install && composer codecept bootstrap"
}
```

I've already defined dependencies and it works perfectly on POSIX compliant machines (MAC/Linux based OS), but when someone who is using windows wants to use any of the scripts, it simply doesn't work.

Problem I'm facing is, I've got `/` as directory separator but windows understands `\` I thought windows was smart enough to automatically convert this.

Dirty solution what I'm thinking of would be to have windows-lint command which is really really annoying. I just wanted to know what other people are doing when they want to work on multiple OS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting question, by the way one may want to make something compatible with windows without seeing the result with his own eyes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use scripts without specifying `vendor/bin` path, it will be done by composer automatically, see the **Note** section in https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#writing-custom-commands

```
"scripts": {
    "document": "apigen generate -s ./src -d ./docs",
    "codecept": "codecept",
    "test": "codecept run",
    "lint": "phpcs --standard=PSR2 src",
    "bootstrap": "composer install && composer codecept bootstrap"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking at the same problem, there may be multiple solutions.

## Option 1, no shell script, pure PHP only

The shell script interpreter differs between your platforms, and it's quite hard to make something "universal" enough.

But you may use only pure PHP. Composer documents [this quite well](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md). Your PHP should be able to adapt easily things for the Windows case or for the POSIX case.

However you may not like wrapping external programs call and shell commands inside a PHP.

## Option 2, run the scripts from a Linux VM

You would for example launch the Linux VM defined by a [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) file, and then run composer trough "vagrant ssh".

Pros:

- Same shell for everyone
- Defining correctly a Vagrant environment may simplify a lot of local tests by developers, removing the well-known "this works on my machine". Every developer has the "same" local environment.

Cons:

- Some initial setup (including the two-side sync of the project folder with appropriate permissions), lot of examples online may help.
- Running a VM locally requires enough RAM.

## Option 3, use another shell than cmd on Windows

Don't use the standard shell to launch composer. There are plenty of other options, including:

- cygwin (I wouldn't use it if I may avoid however)
- git bash (something like MINGW32 that may be installed easily with the git client, using git is not mandatory)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a composer package, which converts slashes to backslashes, if executed on Windows OS.

In your composer.json you just need to add:

```
{
  "require": {
    "instituteweb/composer-scripts": "^1.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": [
      "\\InstituteWeb\\ComposerScripts\\ImprovedScriptExecution::apply",
      "vendor/bin/whatever"
    ]
  }
}
```

So when you perform `composer run test`, it will work on Unix and Windows OS.

**How it works:**

The *apply* method in script queue, stops propagation of the original "test" command. Instead, it creates and executes a new command called "_test" (prepends underscore) which contains the original commands, just with converted slashes.

Just commands **after** the *apply* method call are affected.

Link to package: https://packagist.org/packages/instituteweb/composer-scripts